# python tkinter treeview sort tree not columns

Tags: python, sorting, tkinter, treeview

I see quite a few examples of sorting columns in python tkinter treeview, but not the tree itself.

Of course, maybe the tree is considered a column, but then I do not know what the name of the tree column would be.

I have scanned the docs for something like tree.sort but there seems to be no such method.

I am fairly new to treeview and any help is much appreciated

Comment: The name of the first column is `#0`.

Comment: Hi Henry, thanks again for pointing out the name of the tree column.
I the past day I have been trying out all kinds of code to sort the tree, based on the examples I find on stack, but I have had no success.
Also I cant seem to find any documentation on treesort
Could you give me some example code?
All I would like to do is define a function that sorts the tree itself.
Thanks ahead of time.....

Comment: I posted my code and a new question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55268613/python-tkinter-treeview-sort-tree