# python tkinter treeview sort tree

Tags: python, sorting, tkinter

based on examples and Henry's help I have come up with the following code to sort the tree in a tkinter treeview, but it does not work.
I do not get any errors but the tree is not sorted.
Any help is appreciated.

```
def treeview_sort_column(tv, col, reverse):
    l = [(tv.set(k, col), k) for k in tv.get_children('')]
    l.sort(key=lambda t: int(t[0]), reverse=reverse)
    #      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

    for index, (val, k) in enumerate(l):
        tv.move(k, '', index)

    tv.heading(col,
               command=lambda: treeview_sort_column(tv, col, not reverse))


def SortTree():

    columns = ('#0',)

    for col in columns:
        tree.heading(col, text=col,
                         command=lambda c=col: treeview_sort_column(tree, c, False))
```

Comment: Did you execute `SortTree`? You should get a `_tkinter.TclError: Display column #0 cannot be set` if you did when you do the sorting with the above code.

Comment: Hi, I do run `SortTree` (I have some print statements to make sure) and I do not get any errors if I use `columns = ('#0',)`, if I use `columns = ('#0')` without a comma then I get `_tkinter.TclError: Invalid column index #`

Comment: I feel like I am guessing with this whole code because I cannot seem to find any documentation on this, and examples that I find, they sort other columns, not the tree. A tree item can have features such as text, tag, iid, etc and I am sure I need to specify which one to sort on, but I don't know how to. Any sample code would be appreciated.

Comment: I had shown a sample below to just sort on first column.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since you are just adding the command to column `#0`, you don't have to put it in a loop.

```
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
tree = ttk.Treeview(root,height=10)
tree.pack()

def treeview_sort_column(tv, col, reverse):
    l = [(tv.item(k)["text"], k) for k in tv.get_children()] #Display column #0 cannot be set
    l.sort(key=lambda t: t[0], reverse=reverse)

    for index, (val, k) in enumerate(l):
        tv.move(k, '', index)

    tv.heading(col, command=lambda: treeview_sort_column(tv, col, not reverse))

tree.heading("#0", command=lambda : treeview_sort_column(tree, "#0", False))

for i in range(10):
    tree.insert("",0,text=i)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks again, it was very helpful! Unfortunately I do not have enough Reputation to upvote your answer....

Comment: If it helped, you can check it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

As I wanted to sort by column values alphabetically on clicking the specific column header I made an addition to the function in the answer of [@Henry Yik](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55275988/12285441) and wanted to post for people with the same question in the future.

```
def treeview_sort_column(tv, col, reverse):
    column_index = self.tree["columns"].index(col)
    l = [(str(tv.item(k)["values"][column_index]), k) for k in tv.get_children()]
    l.sort(key=lambda t: t[0], reverse=reverse)

    for index, (val, k) in enumerate(l):
        tv.move(k, '', index)
    
    tv.heading(col, command=lambda: treeview_sort_column(tv, col, not reverse))
```